# Chrome - Block site only if using Incognito

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extensions, private-browsing

There's [this existing question](https://superuser.com/questions/825179/block-site-if-browser-not-in-incognito-chrome) that tells one how to block websites only in normal mode of browsing while letting them remain accessible from the Incognito mode.

I have the opposite question - What can I do to have a website remain blocked only in Incognito but remain accessible in normal mode of browsing?

I'm using Chrome.
From my initial investigation, this seems to be not possible due to Chrome not allowing extensions/tools to run in Incognito exclusively, while something like Opera [apparently does](https://superuser.com/a/1733188/1904837). 
But... I don't want to switch to Opera :)

[Another solution](https://superuser.com/a/265999/1904837) that I found that comes close, suggests maintaining a separate profile for Incognito. But apart from the drawbacks in the linked answer, I really don't want to switch profiles because that defeats the purpose (For example, what prevents someone from switching profiles and using the un-restricted version?)

So is there a way I could hack my way through this and make it work?